# defining the a path for the _parent field

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I use a "path" for the _parent field?

It is mentioned that the _routing field can do that at:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/routing-field/

But at
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field/
it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.
Refer to the issue https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3405